# PySpark convert str to TimestampType

Tags: amazon-s3, pyspark, casting, timestamp

Hello my devoted coders,

First of all, I need you to know that I have tried many of the solutions you may find on the first page of your favorite search engine. It concerned the error:

```
TypeError: field dt: TimestampType can not accept object '2021-05-01T09:19:46' in type <class 'str'>
```

My data are stored in a Amazon S3 bucket as `raw.csv` and look like:

```
2021-05-01T09:19:46,...
2021-05-01T09:19:42,...
2021-05-01T09:19:39,...
```

I have tried:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import to_timestamp
from pyspark.sql.types import *
from awsglue.context import GlueContext
from pyspark.context import SparkContext

df = GlueContext(SparkContext.getOrCreate()).create_dynamic_frame.from_options(
        connection_type="s3",
        connection_options={ 'paths': ["s3://bucket/to/raw.csv"] },
        format="csv",
        format_options={'withHeader': True}
    ).toDF()
events_schema = StructType([
    StructField("dt", TimestampType(), nullable=False),
    # and many other columns
])
df = session.createDataFrame(df.rdd, schema=events_schema)
df.withColumn("dt", to_timestamp("dt", "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss"))\
    .show(1, False)
```

And

```
df.withColumn("dt", unix_timestamp("dt", "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss")\
        .cast("double")
        .cast("timestamp"))\
    .show(1, False)
```

I still have the exact same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try by reading `dt` as **stringtype** then use `df.withColumn` to cast to **`timestamptype`**

**`Example:`**

```
events_schema = StructType([
    StructField("dt", StringType(), nullable=False),
    # and many other columns
])

df = session.createDataFrame(df.rdd, schema=events_schema)
df.show(10,False)
#+-------------------+
#|dt                 |
#+-------------------+
#|2021-05-01T09:19:46|
#+-------------------+

df.withColumn("dt", to_timestamp("dt", "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss")).show()
#+-------------------+
#|                 dt|
#+-------------------+
#|2021-05-01 09:19:46|
#+-------------------+
```

Comment: I used the 2nd porposition with `'timestampFormat':"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss"`. Please note that this argument doesn't exist in the documentation, this is why I tried another way to do it. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/aws-glue-programming-etl-format.html#aws-glue-programming-etl-format-csv

Comment: @Jérémy, Ok.. thats weird I haven't used AWS Glue, but could you try with `stringtype` that I proposed as option1? I believe this should work.

Comment: My bad, the argument `timestampFormat`, did not solve my problem.

Comment: Could you please modify your answer to only keep option1 which solved my problem? I will then validate it as a valid answer.